# Send New Order email to Admin on custom Status

Tags: php, email, woocommerce, status, orders

I have created my custom order status **Pending Approval** as Default Order Status, Means if a customer order something from store, it will place it under **Pending Approval** instead of **Processing**, Here's my code to create custom status:

```
function register_my_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-pending-approval', array(
        'label'                     => 'Pending Approval',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'exclude_from_orders_screen'       => false,
        'add_order_meta_boxes'             => true,
        'exclude_from_order_count'         => false,
        'exclude_from_order_views'         => false,
        'exclude_from_order_webhooks'      => false,
        'exclude_from_order_reports'       => false,
        'exclude_from_order_sales_reports' => false,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Pending Approval <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Pending Approval <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_order_status' );

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_my_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {

    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {

        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;

        if ( 'wc-pending' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-pending-approval'] = 'Pending Approval';
        }
    }

    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_my_order_statuses' );
```

To make it default status, I've edited this file:

`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/cod/class-wc-gateway-cod.php`

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        // Mark as processing (payment won't be taken until delivery)
        //$order->update_status( 'processing', __( 'Payment to be made upon delivery.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        $order->update_status( 'pending-approval', __( 'Payment to be made upon delivery.', 'woocommerce' ) );
...
```

As you can see I've commented default status(Processing) to "Pending Approval"..

Now the Problem is it's not sending New Order emails to Admin & Customers because it's my custom status and it's unknown status for woocommerce, I haven't changed anything other than this for Custom Status, Kindly help me in this regard..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not a valid solution but my problem is resolved, what I've done is:

I set default order status as **Processing**, when all my required emails were sent then I changed the Order status to my custom status **Pending Approval** :P

```
$order->update_status( 'processing', __( 'Payment to be made upon delivery.', 'woocommerce' ) );
$order->update_status( 'pending-approval', __( 'Payment to be made upon delivery.', 'woocommerce' ) );
```

Any valid solution is still required for my learning purpose..

**TIA**